# Finding the linear combination of a vector that is in a span

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So say we have

Span S =
$
        \begin{Bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \end{Bmatrix}
$

I know that 
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        4 \\
        7 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$
is in the span because the reduced row echelon form of [A v] is consistent. Now 
how do I find what exactly the linear combination that makes the vector?

Comment: Suppose there is a linear combination of the three vectors that equals the last one. Looking at the components, you will get a system of equations which you can then solve.

Comment: The vectors are linearly dependent, choose two. This gives a system of the form $Ax=b$, but $A$ is 'tall'. Choose the upper two rows of $A$, this happens (in this case) to be invertible, so you can solve the top two rows easily. Then check that the last row matches.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1\\4\\7\end{pmatrix}=3\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+4\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1\\4\\7\end{pmatrix}=-5\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}+4\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\3\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: How did you get that (by not just guessing/looking at it)?

Comment: Write $(-1,4,7)=a(1,0,1)+b(-1,1,1)+c(1,1,3)$ and look for solutions of the system. There are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your three vectors $u_1,u_2,u_3$  are not independent since

$$u_3-u_2=2u_1$$

thus we will write $v=(-1,4,7)$ as a combination of $u_1$ and $u_2$.

from here, it is easy to see that

$$v=4u_2+3u_1=u_1+3u_2+u_3.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can read the solutions in the *reduced* row echelon form of the augmented matrix:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&-1\\0&1&1&4\\1&1&3&7\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&-1\\0&1&1&4\\0&2&2&8\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&-1\\0&1&1&4\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&2&3\\0&1&1&4\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
The last form says the coefficients $x,y,z$ of a linear combination satisfy the relations:
$$x=-2z+3,\quad y= -z+4,\quad\text{or, in matrix form}\quad
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\0\end{bmatrix}-z\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}.$$
There remains to choose the value of $z$ at your convenience.